# Delphi Hash from a string - a piece of cake?

Tags: string, delphi, hash

Generating Hash from the string  should be a piece of cake i guess, but this don't work. It says  Undeclared identifier:'GetHashString'. Im I missing something here?

```
unit HashCreator;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Hash;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

   private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo2.Text := GetHashString(Memo1.Text,SHA256);
end;
end.
```

Comment: You cannot omit the class names, as then too many functions with the same name would match - you must at least write `THashSHA2.GetHashString` - welcome to OOP, you should have noticed many dots all around already.

Comment: It's not a question of "too many functions would match" but of identifying to the compiler which GetHashString function you wish to call.  What the error message is telling you is that it can't find a globally-scoped function called GetHashString.

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be a piece of cake after all. Thanks for your advices. The following code seem to work fine in Delphi 10.3. Commmunity Edition.

```
unit HashCreator;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Hash;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo2.Text := THashSHA2.GetHashString(Memo1.Text, SHA256);
end;

 end.
```